# Creating sequence diagram for a block using intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sequence-diagram

I have a code snippet like below,

```
if{
....
...
...
}
```

I need to create a sequence diagram for this particular block.with  IntelliJ i can able to create for a method but how can i do for a block of code??

Comment: What plugin are you using for sequence diagrams? This isn't a native feature in Intellij.